# Unable to get films to show on Netflix

Tags: 14.04

I have tried to log into Netflix today, I logged in without any problem and the 'watch instantly' page was displayed.
When I click on a film I get transferred to a 'System compatibility' screen.
I tried contacting their support and was told that they didn't support Linux.
Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Browser version?

Answer (score 0):

Under linux, the only compatible browser is Google chrome. Using it, you will find no problems watching movies and TV shows.